# Apply grayscale effect to a javafx application

Tags: javafx, colors, effect, grayscale

Is it possible to apply an effect to the whole application to change its color? I would like to apply a grayscale for example.

I have seen the [ColorAdjust](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/ColorAdjust.html) effect but i'm not sure i can use it for a grayscale effect.

Comment: When you are able to, please edit the question to remove the solution and add the solution as a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, it's pretty simple. To apply an effect to the whole application, use the setEffect method on the root node. For a grayscale effect, set the saturation of the [ColorAdjust](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/ColorAdjust.html) to the value -1

```
ColorAdjust grayscale = new ColorAdjust();
grayscale.setSaturation(-1);
stage.getScene().getRoot().setEffect(grayscale);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is possible I would not reccomend it for any larger application because it is most certainly a real performance killer due to the way effects are implemented.